# product duplicate rule

Tags: product

I am trying to add a quick matching/duplicate rule for Products, but i cannot even find the right object listed in the matching rule section.

[image]

Matching Rules - Product

I am unsure which object should I choose? Pls help/guide
P.S. I want my rule on the ProductCode field.

Comment: Hi @steve, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @MartinLezer I do apologize If I was not specific enough. That is purely my mistake. I own it:) 
Though honestly I am unsure what more should I have added? just asking for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put Duplicate Rules on a Product. However, you could create a unique indexed field on the Product, then set a Workflow Rule to copy the Product Code to your custom unique field. On a duplicate entry, you'll get an error message regarding uniqueness.

Comment: @sfdcfoc Thank you so much for your help. It helps but I am stuck at this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjIfAAK

Can you Please throw some ideas on how can I accomplish this? maybe via custom trigger? 

Since the above suggestion "works" for me but is not entirely user friendly. Any ideas top of your head?

Comment: @steve You could write a trigger, but I was simply trying to give you a non-code solution. If you need a custom message, your only possible choice right now is to use code.